how to fix realsense2 pcl_conversion error
colcon build
Starting >>> realsense2_camera_msgs
Starting >>> labview_r2interface
Starting >>> rf2o_laser_odometry
Starting >>> sick_scan2
Starting >>> warehousebot_description
Finished <<< warehousebot_description [0.16s]                              
Finished <<< rf2o_laser_odometry [0.20s]                                   
Finished <<< sick_scan2 [0.28s]
Finished <<< labview_r2interface [0.48s]                                   
Finished <<< realsense2_camera_msgs [1.30s]                     
Starting >>> realsense2_camera
Starting >>> realsense2_description
Finished <<< realsense2_description [0.27s]                           
--- stderr: realsense2_camera                             
In file included from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/../include/base_realsense_node.h:51,
                 from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/base_realsense_node.cpp:15:
/home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/include/named_filter.h:24:10: fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/../include/base_realsense_node.h:51,
                 from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/rs_node_setup.cpp:15:
/home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/include/named_filter.h:24:10: fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/../include/base_realsense_node.h:51,
                 from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/../include/realsense_node_factory.h:19,
                 from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/realsense_node_factory.cpp:15:
/home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/include/named_filter.h:24:10: fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/../include/base_realsense_node.h:51,
                 from /home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/src/parameters.cpp:15:
/home/matthew/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/include/named_filter.h:24:10: fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/base_realsense_node.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/build.make:118: CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/rs_node_setup.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/realsense_node_factory.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/parameters.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< realsense2_camera [6.97s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 6 packages finished [8.44s]
  1 package failed: realsense2_camera
  1 package had stderr output: realsense2_camera





/ros2_ws/install/realsense2_camera/share/realsense2_camera/local_setup.bash
 is also missing


Is there a question??   It appears you've provided only a paste, and not actually given any context and actual problem to solve.
